# Change `max` or `min` dynamically in html5 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've problem with change `max` in `<input type='number'>` . this is my code for sample :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var total = 5;
  $(.foo).attr('max', total);
  $(.bar).attr('max', total);
  $(.ext).attr('max', total);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input type='number' name='foo' class='foo'>
  <br>
  <input type='number' name='bar'  class='bar'>
  <br>
  <input type='number' name='ext'  class='ext'>
  
  </body>
```

How to make the `max` must be not > total ?

example : if i input 2 on foo and input 1 on bar, on ext must not be greater than 2 .

thanks

Comment: You have `$(.foo)`, you need `$(".foo")`. You should also use IDs for unique elements, as opposed to classes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by Chris, it should be `'.foo'` instead of `.foo`. Also as a shorthand you can have them in one single statement as below like, `$('.foo, .bar, .ext')` if all have the same `max`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var total = 5;
  $('.foo, .bar, .ext').attr('max', total);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form action="http://stackoverflow.com">
  <input type='number' name='foo' class='foo'>
  <br>
  <input type='number' name='bar'  class='bar'>
  <br>
  <input type='number' name='ext'  class='ext'>
  <br>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit' >
  </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to limit the total of any combination of the three inputs to 5.  Here's one way to do that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var total = 5;
  var remain;

  var $foo = $("#foo");
  var $bar = $("#bar");
  var $ext = $("#ext");

  recalculateMax = function(el)
  {
    switch (el) {
      case $foo[0]:
        remain = total - $bar.val() - $ext.val();
        remain = remain < 0 ? 0 : remain
        $foo.val(($foo.val() <= remain) ? $foo.val() : remain);
        break;
      case $bar[0]:
        remain = total - $foo.val() - $ext.val();
        remain = remain < 0 ? 0 : remain
        $bar.val(($bar.val() <= remain) ? $bar.val() : remain);
        break;
      case $ext[0]:
        remain = total - $foo.val() - $bar.val();
        remain = remain < 0 ? 0 : remain
        $ext.val(($ext.val() <= remain) ? $ext.val() : remain);
        break;
    } 
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input id="foo" type='number' name='foo' onChange="recalculateMax(this)">
  <br>
  <input id="bar" type='number' name='bar' onChange="recalculateMax(this)">
  <br>
  <input id="ext" type='number' name='ext' onChange="recalculateMax(this)">
</body>
```

Comment: And if you want to prevent the numbers going negative you can just add the attribute `min="0"` to each `input`